# Passing parameters to a function in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii. I've created a custom in button in CGridView that has a class of CButtonColumn. I'm just wondering how can I pass parameters that I can add to my php function in my model.

This is my custom button in the table

```
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{approve}, {update},{delete}',
        'buttons'=>array(

            'approve' => array(
                'label'=>'Approve',
                'options'=>array(),
                'click'=>$model->approveRegistrants("$user_id, $category", array("id"=>$data->user_id , "category"=>$data->category),
                )
           )
     )
```

and this is my function is

```
public function approveRegistrants($user_id, $category){

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secret; charset=utf8', 'Andy', '*****');
$getCounter = "SELECT registrants FROM counter order by registrants desc limit 1;";
$bool = false;
$show = '0';


do{
    $result = $db->query($getCounter);
    // $registrants = $db->query($getCounter);
    // $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $registrants = '1'; 

foreach ($result as $value){
    $registrants = $value['registrants'];
    echo 'hello'.$registrants.'</br>';
}

    // $registrants = $result['registrants'];
    // print_r($registrants);
    $max_registrants = '3400';
        if($max_registrants > $registrants){

        // pdo that will use $updateCounterByOne
        $updateCounterByOne = "UPDATE counter set registrants = registrants + 1 WHERE registrants = ". $registrants .";";
        $updateCounter = $db->prepare($updateCounterByOne);
        $updateCounter->execute();

        // return affected rows
        $returnAffectedRows = $updateCounter->rowCount();
        $bool = true;
        // break;
        }
        else{
        echo "No more slot Available";
        // break;
        }
}while($returnAffectedRows == '0');


if($bool = true){
    //sql syntax
    $selectApprovedUser = "SELECT user_id FROM registrants WHERE user_id = '". $user_id ."';";

    //pdo that will use $selectApprovedUser
    $updateApprovedUser = "UPDATE registrants set approved = 'YES' where user_id = ". $selectApprovedUser .";";
    $updateApproved = $db->prepare($updateApprovedUser);
    $updateApproved->execute();

    //pdo that will use $insertApprovedUser
    $insertApprovedUser = "INSERT INTO approved_registrants (user_id, category, approved_date) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$category."', 'curdate()');";
    $insertApproved = $db->prepare($insertApprovedUser);
    $insertApproved->execute();

    //execute trial
    $selectSomething = "SELECT registrants from counter where tandem = '0'";
    $doSelect = $db->prepare($selectSomething);
    $doSelect->execute();
    $hello = $doSelect->fetchAll();
    echo $hello[0]['registrants'];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that you are bypassing the controller fully here.

buttons column is configured with the following parameters

```
'buttonID' => array(
    'label'=>'...',     // text label of the button
    'url'=>'...',       // a PHP expression for generating the URL of the button
    'imageUrl'=>'...',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used
    'options'=>array(...), // HTML options for the button tag
    'click'=>'...',     // a JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked
    'visible'=>'...',   // a PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible
)
```

See [CButtonColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail) for details.

As you can see `click` has to be a js function that will be called on clicking the button. You can rewrite your button like this

```
array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{approve}, {update},{delete}',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'approve' => array(
                'label'=>'Approve',
                'options'=>array(),
                // Alternative -1 Url Method -> will cause page to change to approve/id
                 'url'=>'array("approve","id"=>$data->id)',  
                //  Alternative -2 Js method -> use 1,2 not both
                'click'=>'js:approve()',
                )
           )
     )
```

in your CGridView configuration you add

```
array( 
      ....
     'id'=>'gridViewID', //Unique ID for grid view
     'rowHtmlOptionsExpression'=> 'array("id"=>$data->id)', 
)
```

so that each row has the unique ID, ( you can do the same to a button, but it slightly more difficult as $data is not available there)

in your js function you can do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function approve(){
        id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
        <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array( // You also can directly write your ajax 
            'url'=>array('approve'),
            'type'=>'GET',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'data'=>array('id'=>'js:id'),
            'success'=>'js:function(json){
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update("gridViewID",{}); 
                            // this will refresh the view, you do some other logic here like a confirmation box etc

            }'
        ));?>
    }
</script>
```

Finally your approve action

```
class YourController extend CController {

......

public function actionApprove(){
   id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');
   $dataModel = MyModel::model()->findByPk($id); // This is the model has the $user_id, and $category
   ....
   $OtherModel->approve($dataModel->user_id,$dataModel->category) // if approve is in the same model you can self reference the values of category and user_id directly no need to pass as parameters.
   // Do some logic based on returned value of $otherModel->approve() 
   // return the values from the approve() function and echo from here if required back to the view, directly echoing output makes it difficult to debug which function and where values are coming from .
   Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: Do you know a little not complicated way? I'm not using any javascript as of now. I just wanted to know how to pass values via php.

Comment: ah well, The only way to do without out js/ajax, is to make a get request directly to the action from the button url, using the button 'url' attribute. Note this will call the page to change and you can have fresh view for that page there. I have modified the button params for this